# Mocha tests run fine locally, but fail on Travis due to destructuring syntax?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, travis-ci, chai

I have a NodeJS + Express app running and I am trying to test my API via Mocha tests. These tests run fine locally via an npm script (which is also the same script being called by Travis), but when run on Travis I run into the error below:

```
> mocha --exit
/home/travis/build/tristonpang/restful-web-cs3219/node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha:13
const {deprecate} = require('../lib/utils');
      ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:54:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:429:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:464:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:341:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:296:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:487:10)
    at startup (node.js:111:16)
    at node.js:809:3
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
The command "npm test" exited with 1.
```

My package.json is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "task-b",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "App demonstrating RESTful implentation.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index",
    "test": "mocha --exit"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "restful"
  ],
  "author": "Triston Pang Erh Syen",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "chai-http": "^4.3.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "chai-like": "^1.1.1",
    "mocha": "^8.1.3"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015"
    ]
  }
}
```

Having searched all over the place and not finding any solution, I am rather stumped as to why this is happening, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem, it was a typo in the `.travis.yml` file that set the node version to 1.0.0, way before destructuring was introduced.